# How to Configure Ehcache JMX Monitoring on JBoss

Tags: jboss7.x, jmx, ehcache

I am using Ehcache in my application. I need to monitor cache statistics using JMX. Ehcache provides an api net.sf.ehcache.management for the same.

Please let me know, how to proceed further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation on this topic can be found [here](http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.10.1/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fco-jmx_jconsole_example.html%23wwconnect_header), it should give you insights on what you need to do.